How to select q-points for phonon dispersion?
today I'm simply asking what are the principles behind the selection of the q-points to calculate the phonon dispersion in the "Quantum ESPRESSO" code: expecially I'd like to ask whether the selection should take in account the previously selected K point grid, or the symmetry of the overall cell.
I know what's their physical meaning is, but the only piece of advice I always receive is to select q-grid for ph.x (nq1, nq2, nq3) in order to be smaller than the one used in the pw.x calculations (both nscf and scf).
Thank you in advance!

Other than nq1, nq2, nq3 being smaller than k1, k2, k3, they at least need to be compatible too. So for a $6 \times 6 \times 6$ k-grid, you could use a $1 \times 1\times 1, 2\times 2\times 2, 3\times 3\times 3$ or $6\times 6\times 6$ but not $4\times 4\times 4$ or $5 \times 5 \times 5$. Unfortunately I cannot give you any reference for this right now but if I recall correctly, I found this in either 2023 or 2024 lectures on DFPT in the MAX-QE Hubbard Koopmans school.
